# Is there a java setting for disabling certificate validation?

Tags: java, ssl-certificate

I received this error while trying to start up an application:

```
Sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: 
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException:  java.net.UnknownHostException:oscp.thawte.com
```

The application is behind a closed network and won't ever be able to get to oscp.thawte.com. Is there a java setting that can disable this?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

`-Dcom.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation=false`

Comment: Where should I execute this?

Comment: it is a command line parameter for the JVM.  You can also set it programmatically http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189914/setting-system-property

Comment: Using OpenJDK 6 this isn't working to me. (it's probably Sun-specific)

Comment: well it is referenced in OpenJDK code http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/37a05a11f281/src/share/classes/sun/security/ssl/X509TrustManagerImpl.java Try to check which TrustManager you are using.

Comment: Hi! I tried to set this in my `MAVEN_OPTS` environment variable on windows 7, so that my `mvn` could connect to a private repo w/o SSLHandshake ex. It did not work for me though. Any Ideas?

Comment: I think Maven is special, see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252800/how-to-tell-maven-to-disregard-ssl-errors-and-trusting-all-certs

Comment: Doesn't work with Java 8 for me. I used System.setProperty("com.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation", "false") in my code. The property does get set but has no effect.

Comment: does this work? https://web.archive.org/web/20180104182116/https://log.rowanto.com/java-8-turning-off-ssl-certificate-check/

Comment: I'm using
openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_292-b10)
this option doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 23):

Not exactly a setting but you can override the default TrustManager and HostnameVerifier to accept anything. Not a safe approach but in your situation, it can be acceptable.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The property mentioned in accepted answer does not take effect on many JVMs.

Answer (score 21):

In addition to the answers above. You can do it programmatically by implementing the TrustManager:

```
TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
        new X509TrustManager() {
          public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
           return null;
          }
          @Override
          public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
           throws CertificateException {}

          @Override
          public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
            throws CertificateException {}
          }
     };

  SSLContext sc=null;
  try {
   sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
  } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  try {
   sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
  } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
  // Create all-trusting host name verifier
  HostnameVerifier validHosts = new HostnameVerifier() {
  @Override
  public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
   return true;
  }
  };
  // All hosts will be valid
  HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(validHosts);
```

However this is not a good practice for production.

This example on [How to disable SSL certificat validation in Java](https://tutoref.com/how-to-disable-ssl-certificat-validation-in-java/) contains a utility class you can copy in your project.

Comment: worked at first attempt. Thanks!!

Comment: Can you tell me what version of apache client  you are using. This does not work for later versions such as version 4.5.13

Comment: Can you tell me what version of java you are using, and what version of Apache Client.

Comment: @AntonCavanaugh at the time of writing this answer I was using java 8.

Answer (score 10):

Use cli utility **keytool** from java software distribution for import (and **trust!**) needed certificates

Sample:

1. From cli change dir to jre\bin
2. Check keystore (file found in jre\bin directory)
   keytool -list -keystore ..\lib\security\cacerts
   Enter keystore password: **changeit**
3. Download and save all certificates chain from needed server.
4. Add certificates (before need to remove "read-only" attribute on file "..\lib\security\cacerts") 
   keytool -alias REPLACE_TO_ANY_UNIQ_NAME -import -keystore ..\lib\security\cacerts -file "r:\root.crt"

accidentally I found such a simple tip. 
Other solutions require the use of InstallCert.Java and JDK

source: http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=210

Answer (score 3):

On my Mac that I'm sure I'm not going to allow java anyplace other than a specific site, I was able to use Preferences->Java to bring up the Java control panel and turned the checking off.  If DLink ever fixes their certificate, I'll turn it back on.

[image: Java control panel - Advanced]

Comment: And how do i open this file?

Comment: How do I get this to do on Macos Moneterey, I believe there is no Java Control Panel

Answer (score 2):

In Axis webservice and if you have to disable the certificate checking then use below code:

AxisProperties.setProperty("axis.socketSecureFactory","org.apache.axis.components.net.SunFakeTrustSocketFactory");

Answer (score -6):

It is very simple .In my opinion it is the best way for everyone

```
       Unirest.config().verifySsl(false);
       HttpResponse<String> response = null;
       try {
           Gson gson = new Gson();
           response = Unirest.post("your_api_url")
                   .header("Authorization", "Basic " + "authkey")
                   .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                   .body("request_body")
                   .asString();
           System.out.println("------RESPONSE -------"+ gson.toJson(response.getBody()));
       } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println("------RESPONSE ERROR--");
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
```

Comment: Are you sure this will help? I'm not sure if the poster is trying to make a ws call himself.