# Netbeans: How to change look and feel of JTree

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtree

I am using Net-beans for developing a small desktop application. I am using a `Jtree` in this application. Referring to the following tutorial:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#display

I want to customize  the look and feel of my `JTree` to the "Java Look and Feel" (First fig from left). How should I achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

You generally don't change the look and feel of a unique component, but the look and feel of the entire application.

See the [Swing tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) for explanations.

It's perhaps possible to change the look and feel of a single component, but then the application would be inconsistent. I would never do that.

Answer (score 2):

This is something you should look into : [Pluggable look-and-feel architecture](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/architecture-142923.html#pluggable) : Swing's pluggable look-and-feel architecture allows us to provide a single component API without dictating a particular look-and-feel. The Swing toolkit provides a default set of look-and-feels; however, the API is "open" -- a design that additionally allows developers to create new look-and-feel implementations by either extending an existing look-and-feel or creating one from scratch.

And as per the suggestion of @JB Nizet , if you prefer to change the LaF of the application , this might be helpful : [Look and Feel in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954616/look-and-feel-in-java/3954646#3954646)

Answer (score 0):

I used this change my swing app's view to **windows look and feel**.

As I referred from this [swing docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) and this [property docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189914/setting-system-property).
This is how we change the look and feel using command line args.

`java -Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel MyApp
java -Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel MyApp`

But, this is how we do programmatically using these below lines.

`Properties properties = System.getProperties();
properties.
setProperty("swing.defaultlaf","com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");`