# How to set a system property (java.awt.headless=true) on system startup

Tags: java, jasper-reports, awt

I found this exception when I run jasperreport in application(Rational Application Developer:RAD) :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser (initialization failure)
```

After this I found solution, I should setting

```
java.awt.headless=true
```

I don't know how to setting this order, Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: That would depend on how you are running the report, but you can pass properties to the jvm using the `-D` flag

Comment: possible duplicate of [setting system property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189914/setting-system-property)