# How to set properties attributes in Java programmatically?

Tags: java, properties, sentry, raven

I'm looking over [sentry for java](https://docs.getsentry.com/hosted/clients/java/modules/raven/) and it requires a properties file:

```
.level=WARN
handlers=net.kencochrane.raven.jul.SentryHandler
net.kencochrane.raven.jul.SentryHandler.dsn=https://<key>:<secret>@app.getsentry.com/<project>
net.kencochrane.raven.jul.SentryHandler.tags=tag1:value1,tag2:value2
```

It loads the file by: `java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/path/to/app.properties MyClass`

I want to set the properties in java source; how do I do that?

It looks like I may be able to use the [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class? Not sure though (Java isn't my primary language).

Comment: Do you want to set the properties into the file at runtime or to read the properties from the file at runtime?

Comment: Please see if the link helps you [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189914/setting-system-property)

Comment: this can also hepls you [writing to prop](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java you can [set properties](http://[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setProperty(java.lang.String][1]) dynamically by using the System class , just doing  for example
`System.setProperty("java.library.path","value_you_want");` you can achieve it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set property dinamically at runtime, you may use following code:

```
Properties props = null;
FileInputStream fis = null;
String propFile = "path_to_your_file_with_properties";

try {
    fis = new FileInputStream(propFile);
    props.load(fis)
    props.setProperty("key", "value");
} catch (Exception e) {
    //handle exception here
} finally {
    //close FileInputStream
}
```