# Pass runtime arguments in Gatling

Tags: performance-testing, gatling

I am trying to pass runtime args while running gatling tests for couple of fields. For example I am trying to pass number of users dynamically when running the test. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is going for Java system properties, for example if you have [workload model](https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/simulation_setup/) defined as:

```
setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1)).protocols(httpProtocol))
```

if you change it from hard-coded to dynamic reading of the [system property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) like:

```
setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("userCount")))).protocols(httpProtocol))
```

you will be able to pass the desired number of users dynamically via [`-D` command-line argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189914/setting-system-property/5189966) like:

```
gatling.bat -DuserCount=5 -s computerdatabase.BasicSimulation
```

More information: [Gatling Installation, Verification and Configuration - the Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/gatling-installation-verification-and-configuration-the-ultimate-guide)

Answer (score 3):

This is documented in the [official documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/current/cookbook/passing_parameters/):

> This can be done very easily with additional JAVA_OPTS in the launch script:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Dusers=500 -Dramp=3600"

val nbUsers = Integer.getInteger("users", 1)
val myRamp = java.lang.Long.getLong("ramp", 0L)
setUp(scn.inject(rampUsers(nbUsers).during(myRamp.seconds)))

// Of course, passing a String is just as easy as:

JAVA_OPTS="-Dfoo=bar"

val foo = System.getProperty("foo")
```