# Setting up TeamCity with my own GIT Server over SSL

Tags: git, ssl, https, teamcity

I have my own GIT server repository and can be connected via HTTPS protocol.

I am trying to setup TeamCity to connect to my GIT repo but I am unable to because of the HTTPS protocol.

In Eclipse, I have a setting that sets sslVerify=false and I can connect to my GIT repo and perform my task.

How can i achieve the same for TeamCity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [issue TW-30210](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-30210) illustrates, it can depends on the version of TeamCity and Java you are using.

It also depends if your certificate is self-signed or not.
If is is signed (and validate by an actual CA - Certificate Authority), then you need to add it in your java keystore (used by TeamCity): see "[Using HTTPS to access TeamCity server](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Using+HTTPS+to+access+TeamCity+server)".

If you just want to disable ssl verification, you can do on the TeamCity server:

- [for git commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11622001/6309), and
- [for the java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4663241/6309) you are using to run the TeamCity server.

  ```
  -Dcom.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation=false
  ```

But that is considered as a bad practice.

Comment: Hey VonC, I just added my cert using keytool but teamcity still complains, is a restart required or java or something else?

Answer (score 5):

Addition for answer above with samples for default setup:

```
openssl s_client -connect <githost>:443 </dev/null | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > /opt/exported.cert
keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias <githost> -file /opt/exported.cert -keystore ${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit
```

Where,

**githost**  - domain name of host with git repo

Answer (score 1):

We were using 32-bit version of git on teamcity server (64-bit). So removing 32-bit and installing 64-bit git bash and git cmd helped resolve the GIT and Teamcity connection problem for us.
I hope this help some users.