# Teamcity + GitLab, SSL disable doesn't work

Tags: java, git, bash, ssl, teamcity

I have a problem with configuring GitLab in TeamCity

TeamCity version: 2017.1.4 (build 47070), GitLab version: 9.4.5

I did everything as described here:
[Setting up TeamCity with my own GIT Server over SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21127793/setting-up-teamcity-with-my-own-git-server-over-ssl)

But I still have a mistake:

> Connection failed!
>   List remote refs failed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid

If I make git clone in cmd or in git bash on the TeamCity server, everything goes well and there are no errors

[image: -Dcom.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation=false - done]

[image: git config - done]

Help me please, I try to solve this problem a few days

Comment: http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=210
it solved my problem, I just imported my certificate
maybe this will help someone
P.S. I still do not understand why ssl verify = false did not work