# How to tell Maven to disregard SSL errors (and trusting all certs)?

Tags: maven, ssl-certificate

I frequently need to run "mvn" command :

```
mvn -f pom.xml clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=false --settings /Users/myhome/settings.xml -X -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/Users/myhome/truststore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=JKS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=dummy -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol -U
```

As I need to integrate with various other domains, so currently every time I have to add their certificate to my truststore.jks to prevent SSL handshake errors.

Is there any way I can configure mvn to ignore SSL errors.

Answer (score 398, accepted):

You can disable SSL certificate checking by adding one or more of these command line parameters:

- `-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true` - enable use of relaxed SSL check for user generated certificates.
- `-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true` - enable match of the server's X.509 certificate with hostname. If disabled, a browser like check will be used.
- `-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true` - ignore issues with certificate dates.
- `-Dmaven.resolver.transport=wagon` - In Maven 3.9.0 and newer, they've switched to using Apache HttpClient 4 by default. You need to use this to switch back to `wagon` for the above flags to work.

Official documentation: http://maven.apache.org/wagon/wagon-providers/wagon-http/

Here's the oneliner for an easy copy-and-paste:

```
-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true
```

[Ajay Gautam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/138969/ajay-gautam) suggested that you could also add the above to the `~/.mavenrc` file as not to have to specify it every time at command line:

```
$ cat ~/.mavenrc 
MAVEN_OPTS="-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true"
```

Comment: I have spring boot /maven project and I am using maven-jaxb2-plugin to generate sources of a  webservice. but the certificate expired. So I tried running the maven generate sources with the above agruments  in Eclipse. But I still get the error  " timestamp check failed "  any idea how to solve it in an eclipse / maven  environment.

Comment: The answer does not work for me. I am using maven 3.5.0 and the exceptions I received was `PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`. Does wagon work with MAven 3.5.0?

Comment: Instead, I created a truststore jks and pointed maven to this jks file.

Comment: By Installing the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength (for [JDK7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html) | for [JDK8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html)) fix issue for me on maven 3.5.0

Comment: Using netbeans 6.8 I added the options to the netbeans maven options under 'Global Execution Options' through the UI and I was able to download from repositories using https.

Comment: With Maven 3.3.9 this does not work. I had to use Richard's answer below, adding the insecure mirror to my settings.xml.

Comment: Dan675, Works like a charm!

Comment: Where to add those proprieties?

Comment: Please note that `maven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true` only works once  you set `maven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true` as well.

Comment: -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true worked for me, running from behind a client proxy that intercepts on SSL.

Comment: I get an error as if I'm using a bad syntax: `mvn install -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true -DskipTests --batch-mode --no-transfer-progress`  ==> `[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase ".wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, .... -> [Help 1]`

Comment: If you're on Maven 3.9.0, you also need to add this: `-Dmaven.resolver.transport=wagon`

Comment: i was missing the 'transport' port. you saved my day..

Comment: Iam using this command `mvn clean install Dmaven.resolver.transport=wagon Dmaven.resolver.transport=wagon -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true`  Maven version is 3.9.4 and JDK 17.  but still the same issue is coming

Answer (score 50):

An alternative that worked for me is to tell Maven to use http: instead of https: when using Maven Central by adding the following to [settings.xml](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html):

```
<settings>
   .
   .
   .
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>central-no-ssl</id>
        <name>Central without ssl</name>
        <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
   .
   .
   .
</settings>
```

Your mileage may vary of course.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! And please a note to revert once SSL works because this could lead to users adding non-standard repositories which could host who knows what

Comment: This doesn't work since Jan 2020 because Maven repo disabled http connection

Comment: Will get this error since Jan 2020:  ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required" , because Maven repo disabled Http connection

Comment: This worked for me.  However, I had to add https instead in the URL.  Not sure why.

Comment: This won't work because unsecured http connections are 501 blocked as of Jan 2020. It impacts a few more places than just Central. JCenter, Spring, and Gradle repos are https required too.  Read more:
 Jan 2020, https://www.alphabot.com/security/blog/2020/java/Your-Java-builds-might-break-starting-January-13th.html

Answer (score 48):

Create a folder `${USER_HOME}/.mvn` 
and put a file called `maven.config` in it.

The content should be:

```
-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true
-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true
-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I succeed on directly using those parameters on the command line, but still failed when adding them into the file

Comment: This should actually be configured on project level.
http://maven.apache.org/configure.html#mvn-folder

Comment: worked like a charm. I was able to do it under console but not within the IDE

Comment: I made it work on my IntelliJ IDE by adding them here: Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven > Importing > VM options

Answer (score 4):

Refer to https://maven.apache.org/resolver/configuration.html, just set `aether.connector.https.securityMode=insecure`. It works for me with Maven 3.9.4.

Comment: Another useful link since Maven 3.9 : https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-resolver-transport.html

Answer (score 3):

If for any reason `maven.config` should not work:

Try set the content as a environment variable.

Example:

```
MAVEN_OPTS="-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2"
```

*After setting the environment variable, you can simply run your `mvn` command.*

**For a short test you can set the environment variable for a session**

Powershell:

```
$env:MAVEN_OPTS="-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2"
```

Bash:

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2"
```

CMD:

```
set MAVEN_OPTS="-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2"
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that the latest jdk16 will fail SSL certificates so I have to use the
`-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true` to work around;  switching to jdk11(LTS) then all problems are gone.

Also jdk1.8 was tested too, which also worked without any parameters; but jdk1.8 is in in no-update mode, better move on to the LTS jdk versions, but not the latest jdk16.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put all the same `maven.wagon.http.ssl.` settings into `~/.m2/settings.xml` instead of `~/.mavenrc`, this is what you need to put in the file:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>definedInM2SettingsXML</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <maven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure>true</maven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure>
        <maven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall>true</maven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall>
        <maven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates>true</maven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</settings>
```

Comment: Apparently, Maven only interprets system properties set in command line or in the MAVEN_ARGS variable. All properties set in settings.xml are available only in Maven running context, to be used in pom.xml file and so. It seems it is too late to configure that kind of Maven behavior in settings.xml. Btw, putting them in settings.xml didn't work for me, I had to rely on MAVEN_ARGS to clean up our command lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can also configure m2e to use HTTP instead of HTTPS

[force-m2e-to-use-http-instead-of-https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32050244/force-m2e-to-use-http-instead-of-https)

Answer (score -1):

-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true - enable use of relaxed SSL check for user generated certificates.

Comment: This Answer is not different from the existing Answer(s).