# jars are missing on `artifactory` server after installing primefaces all-themes

Tags: maven, primefaces, themes

I am trying to follow http://primefaces.org/themes to get it working.

All community themes are also available in "all-in-one" package.

```
<dependency>  
  <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>  
  <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>  
  <version>1.0.10</version>  
</dependency>
```

I added `primefaces` repository and have `artifactory` running. It says `*.jar` artifact missing.

I can see directories of all themes on local maven repository. However, all jars are missing and can't find them on `artifactory` server either.

Comment: all-themes-1.0.10.jar is missing

Answer (score 72):

You must add repositories:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: For Gradle users `repositories {
maven {
url 'http://repository.primefaces.org'
}
}`

Answer (score 6):

The http://repository.primefaces.org redirects to secure https://repository.primefaces.org, but the the server's certificate can't be trusted based on Java's default trust store.

You have two options:

1. Add the "Let's Encrypt Authority X3" CA cert to the /lib/sercurity/cacerts. (The default password is: *changeit*)
2. Ignore maven's certificate validation: [How to tell Maven to disregard SSL errors (and trusting all certs)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252800/how-to-tell-maven-to-disregard-ssl-errors-and-trusting-all-certs/21266642#21266642)

Comment: Absolutely the right answer if one already has the Primefaces Repo in the <repositories> section of pom.xml.  Eclipse sufficiently obscures the real issue that it was a huge relief to stumble on this answer.  I chose to install the Let's Encrypt cert but can't figure out why the Primefaces folks would use that CA.  I can only imagine the workarounds that are being attempted to address (including some from other suggested answers ... eg. wget on entire section of repo which works but not sustainable).  I'd be hesitant to have Maven disregard SSL issues, though.

Comment: Or use a more modern jdk? Does it contain the issuer then?

Answer (score 2):

Version 1.0.10 does not seem to be available at the moment. You can follow this link to see the latest version:
http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.primefaces.extensions%22%20AND%20a%3A%22all-themes%22

I had this same issue. I fixed it by changing my dependency in my pom.xml file to:

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>  
    <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>   
    <version>1.0.8</version>  
</dependency>
```

Because version 1.0.8 is the latest version I got what I needed. The only difference between what I have and what you have is the the groupId. After changing your groupId and doing a Maven update it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

**Repository**

http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3A%22org.primefaces.extensions%22

or

**Custom**

Step 1 - http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Step 2 - https://themeroller.osnode.com/themeroller/

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.8</version>
</dependency>
```

I have tried with 1.0.10 but failed, 1.0.8 is ok!

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu have a problem with certificates, you have to add using this:

```
apt-get install ca-certificates-java
apt-get install ca-certificates
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the error `Blocked mirror for repositories: [prime-repo (http://repository.primefaces.org, default, releases+snapshots)` and changed my http reference to https, problem solved!

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>prime-repo</id>
    <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
    <url>https://repository.primefaces.org</url>
    <layout>default</layout>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems repo is temporary broken, so you have to download it manualy.

1. Download all dependencies from http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/themes/

Here is how to do that:
[How to download HTTP directory with all files and sub-directories as they appear on the online files/folders list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446635/how-to-download-http-directory-with-all-files-and-sub-directories-as-they-appear/26269730#26269730?newreg=01ea83e8f4634bc2adfc1c88f4f20228)

```
wget -r -np -nH --cut-dirs=3 -R index.html http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/themes/
```

2. Move it to your `~/.m2/repository/org/primefaces/themes` dir
3. Update local repository index [img: NetBeans update index example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSKsd.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue a while ago. I simply downloaded the jar file from Maven and placed the jar file in the *.m2\repository\org\primefaces\themes\all-themes\1.0.10 directory. Then on Eclipse I run maven > update.

Comment: Why? Why not solve the real issue. This is sort of a not to good solution. And your answer has already been given...