# Missing artifact org.primefaces.themes:cupertino:jar:1.0.9

Tags: maven, primefaces

I'm working on a project using liferay 6.1.1 and maven!
I have this error message in pom.xml:

> Missing artifact org.primefaces.themes:cupertino:jar:1.0.9

even if the jar file is already there!
When I tried to deploy the project, everything goes well ... but the warning persists even if the project works good.
Any idea?

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<parent>
    <groupId>com.octave.portlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>octave-portlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.octave.portlet.presentation</groupId>
<artifactId>octave-presentation-portlet</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>bridgev2 presentation portlet</name>
<version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.liferay.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>liferay-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${liferay.maven.plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-css</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.octave.portlet.service.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>octave-service-api</artifactId>
        <version>${pom.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.liferay.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>liferay-faces-bridge-impl</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0-ga1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.liferay.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>liferay-faces-portal</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0-ga1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
        <artifactId>portal-service</artifactId>
        <version>${liferay.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
        <artifactId>util-java</artifactId>
        <version>${liferay.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.portlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>portlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.seam</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-el</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.GA</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cupertino</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: try refreshing the project or navigating to Maven --> Update Project. It most likely is some IDE - maven issue.

Comment: I've already done it... but nothing special!

Comment: Show your pom.xml please. There might be some answers, but to be sure, need more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the primefaces repository to your pom.xml, this post for details:

[primefaces all-themes v 1.0.10 installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21705509/primefaces-all-themes-v-1-0-10-installation)

Answer (score 2):

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: That is exactly what the link in the accepted answer states. Better to mark this post as duplicate of that other one then.