# Missing artifact org.jboss.seam:jboss-el:jar:2.0.0.GA

Tags: eclipse, maven, jboss

I'm working on a project using liferay 6.1.1 and maven! I have this error message in pom.xml "Missing artifact org.jboss.seam:jboss-el:jar:2.0.0.GA" even if the jar file is already there! when I tried to deploy the project, everything goes well ... but the warning persiste even if the project works good.
any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Missing artifact org.primefaces.themes:cupertino:jar:1.0.9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22606832/missing-artifact-org-primefaces-themescupertinojar1-0-9)

Comment: You asked exactly the same question for another artifact 20 minutes before. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22606832/missing-artifact-org-primefaces-themescupertinojar1-0-9

Comment: I know but it isn't about the same file!