# wget: Unable to establish SSL connection

Tags: linux, centos7, wget

I am trying to connect to https://www.example.com/ using wget to download some data.

Tried with --no-check-certificate also but no luck.

I am using Centos 7 and Wget package version 1.14.

**Logs:**

```
Resolving <www.example.com> (www.example.com)....... 34......222
Caching www.xyz.com => ..... 34.....222
Connecting to www.example.com (www.example.com)|.....|:443... connected.
Created socket 3.
Releasing 0x00000000024a27e0 (new refcount 1).
Initiating SSL handshake.
SSL handshake timed out.
Closed fd 3
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [wget returns "Unable to establish SSL connection"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50292852/wget-returns-unable-to-establish-ssl-connection)

Comment: Thanks @frippe, Tried the suggestions but no help, Still facing the same issue. The server which I am trying to connect is supporting only TLS 1.3 and TLS 1.2.