# Unable to establish SSL connection - Ubuntu - Wget

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, wget

I am doing a wget to a RSS feed and receiving following error.

```
    XXY:/var/www/intranet# wget https://www.some.com/intranet-news/143/?rss=on
--2018-12-14 13:44:08--  https://www.some.com/intranet-news/143/?rss=on
Resolving www.some.com... x.x.x.x
Connecting to www.some.com|x.x.x.x|:443... connected.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

I tried `--no-check-certificate` still same error

I am on a ubuntu server

Comment: This could be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28757232/unable-to-establish-ssl-connection-upon-wget-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to establish SSL connection upon wget on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28757232/unable-to-establish-ssl-connection-upon-wget-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)