# sh script does not work : Unable to establish SSL connection

Tags: python, bash, sh

I am using python in windows10, and trying to download the dataset mentioned in :

https://github.com/rmitra/PS-Dataset/blob/master/DownloadDataset.md

I tried sh download_dataset.sh script at cmd and the message says :

Unable to establish SSL connection

and the download keeps failing.

the sh script is :

```
BASE_URL='https://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/PS-Dataset'

SCENE_LIST='4 11 13 14 15 16 20 23 24 30 31 34 36 41 44 49 50 51 53 65 66 67 71 74 76 88 89 90 91 95'

FILE_TYPES='patch_info.txt patchImg.bin pair_patch.txt'

BASE_DOWNLOAD_DIR=$(pwd)/PS-Dataset

for SC in $SCENE_LIST; do
    echo 'Downloading scene '$SC

    REMOTE_SC_DIR=$BASE_URL/$SC
    DOWNLOAD_SC_DIR=$BASE_DOWNLOAD_DIR/$SC

    for FILE_TYPE in $FILE_TYPES; do

        FILE_PATH=$REMOTE_SC_DIR/$FILE_TYPE
        echo $FILE_PATH
        wget -P $DOWNLOAD_SC_DIR -nH --cut-dirs 2 $FILE_PATH
    done
wget -r -np -nH -A jpeg,jpg,png -P $DOWNLOAD_SC_DIR --cut-dirs 2 $REMOTE_SC_DIR/images/
done
```

You can access the site written in BASE_URL, and I can run other downloading sh scripts without any problem, for example google landmark dataset https://github.com/cvdfoundation/google-landmark
.

Is there anything that I am missing ?

Comment: [Try looking at this thread.](https://superuser.com/questions/1182465/wget-returning-error-unable-to-establish-ssl-connection) Have you tried curl?

Comment: @ThomasLee I am very new to sh script. What is curl? I have never heard about

Comment: try --no-check-certificate ? see also:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28757232/unable-to-establish-ssl-connection-upon-wget-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts