# Unable to establish SSL connection upon wget on windows, accessing NASA CDDIS

Tags: ssl, command, connection, wget

I've been using wget to pull some .rnx files from the CDDIS NASA archives. This has been working no problem for ~200 iterations until now. Not sure what happened.

I'm receiving an SSL connection error that occurs on other files in the CDDIS website. when I try the same command for, say, [www.google.com](http://www.google.com), the index file is downloaded fine to the given output directory.

I have found this solution thread for linux which seems like my issue:
[Unable to establish SSL connection upon wget on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28757232/unable-to-establish-ssl-connection-upon-wget-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts?newreg=cbda36c9ffa1415f9fe61755afd31b14)

or

[Unable to establish SSL connection, how do I fix my SSL cert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166950/unable-to-establish-ssl-connection-how-do-i-fix-my-ssl-cert)

I am on Windows 11. To be completely honest despite some googling and toying around with the ports (302/443) based on that thread, it's all a bit opaque on how I can fix this issue myself. Would really appreciate a bit more of a breakdown on how I might approach this problem.

```
>wget -P C:\Users\name\Desktop\brdc http://cddis.nasa.gov/archive/gnss/data/daily/2021/001/21p/BRDC00IGS_R_20210010000_01D_MN.rnx.gz

--2022-05-01 17:47:05--  http://cddis.nasa.gov/archive/gnss/data/daily/2021/001/21p/BRDC00IGS_R_20210010000_01D_MN.rnx.gz
Resolving cddis.nasa.gov (cddis.nasa.gov)... 198.118.199.52
Connecting to cddis.nasa.gov (cddis.nasa.gov)|198.118.199.52|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://cddis.nasa.gov/archive/gnss/data/daily/2021/001/21p/BRDC00IGS_R_20210010000_01D_MN.rnx.gz [following]
--2022-05-01 17:47:05--  https://cddis.nasa.gov/archive/gnss/data/daily/2021/001/21p/BRDC00IGS_R_20210010000_01D_MN.rnx.gz
Connecting to cddis.nasa.gov (cddis.nasa.gov)|198.118.199.52|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov/oauth/authorize?client_id=gDQnv1IO0j9O2xXdwS8KMQ&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fcddis.nasa.gov%2Fproxyauth&state=aHR0cDovL2NkZGlzLm5hc2EuZ292L2FyY2hpdmUvZ25zcy9kYXRhL2RhaWx5LzIwMjEvMDAxLzIxcC9CUkRDMDBJR1NfUl8yMDIxMDAxMDAwMF8wMURfTU4ucm54Lmd6 [following]
--2022-05-01 17:47:05--  https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov/oauth/authorize?client_id=gDQnv1IO0j9O2xXdwS8KMQ&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fcddis.nasa.gov%2Fproxyauth&state=aHR0cDovL2NkZGlzLm5hc2EuZ292L2FyY2hpdmUvZ25zcy9kYXRhL2RhaWx5LzIwMjEvMDAxLzIxcC9CUkRDMDBJR1NfUl8yMDIxMDAxMDAwMF8wMURfTU4ucm54Lmd6
Resolving urs.earthdata.nasa.gov (urs.earthdata.nasa.gov)... 198.118.243.33
Connecting to urs.earthdata.nasa.gov (urs.earthdata.nasa.gov)|198.118.243.33|:443... connected.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

Comment: You should ask on UNIX SE https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @rootkea even if I'm working on windows? Sorry if I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: Sorry, I missed Windows part. You can ask on https://superuser.com then.