# Cannot download images from website with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I'm starting with Scrapy in order to automatize file downloading from websites. As a test, I want to download the jpg files from [this](http://www.kevinsmedia.com/km/mp3z/Fluke/Risotto/) website. My code is based on [the intro tutorial](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) and the [Files and Images Pipeline tutorial](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html) on the Scrapy website.

My code is this:

In settings.py, I have added these lines:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1}

IMAGES_STORE = '/home/lucho/Scrapy/jpg/'
```

My items.py file is:

```
import scrapy

class JpgItem(scrapy.Item):
    image_urls = scrapy.Field()
    images = scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

My pipeline file is:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem

class JpgPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        return item
    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        for image_url in item['image_urls']:
            yield scrapy.Request(image_url)

    def item_completed(self, results, item, info):
        image_paths = [x['path'] for ok, x in results if ok]
        if not image_paths:
            raise DropItem("Item contains no images")
        item['image_paths'] = image_paths
        return item
```

Finally, my spider file is:

```
import scrapy
from .. items import JpgItem

class JpgSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "jpg"
    allowed_domains = ["http://www.kevinsmedia.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.kevinsmedia.com/km/mp3z/Fluke/Risotto/"
    ]

def init_request(self):
    #"""This function is called before crawling starts."""
    return Request(url=self.login_page, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    item = JpgItem()
    return item
```

(**Ideally, I want to download all jpg, without specifying exact web addresses for each file needed**)

The output of "scrapy crawl jpg" is:

```
2015-12-08 19:19:30 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.3.post6+g2d688cd started (bot: jpg)
2015-12-08 19:19:30 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2015-12-08 19:19:30 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'jpg.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['jpg.spiders'], 'COOKIES_ENABLED': False, 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 3, 'BOT_NAME': 'jpg'}
2015-12-08 19:19:30 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2015-12-08 19:19:30 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2015-12-08 19:19:30 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2015-12-08 19:19:30 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: ImagesPipeline
2015-12-08 19:19:30 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2015-12-08 19:19:30 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-12-08 19:19:30 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2015-12-08 19:19:31 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.kevinsmedia.com/km/mp3z/Fluke/Risotto/> (referer: None)
2015-12-08 19:19:31 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.kevinsmedia.com/km/mp3z/Fluke/Risotto/>
{'images': []}
2015-12-08 19:19:31 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-12-08 19:19:31 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 254,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 2975,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 8, 22, 19, 31, 294139),
 'item_scraped_count': 1,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 8, 22, 19, 30, 619918)}
2015-12-08 19:19:31 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

While there seems to be no error, the program is not retrieving the jpg files. In case it matters, I'm using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined `parse()` in your `JpgSpider` class.

Update. This doesn't look like a problem you should be attacking with scrapy now that I can see the URL in your update. WGET might be more appropriate, have a look at the [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446635/how-to-download-http-directory-with-all-files-and-sub-directories-as-they-appear). In particular, look at the first comment to the top answer to see how to use file extension to limit which files you download (`-A jpg`).

Update 2: The parse() routine can get the album art URLs from the `<a>` tag using this code

```
part_urls = response.xpath('//a[contains(., "AlbumArt")]/@href')
```

This returns a list of partial URLs, you will need to add the root URL for the page you are parsing from `response.url`. There are a few % codes in the URLs I've looked at, they may be a problem but try it anyway. Once you have a list of the full URLs, put them into item[]

```
item['image_urls'] = full_urls
yield item
```

This should get scrapy to automatically download the images, so you can remove your middleware and let scrapy do the heavy lifting.

Comment: But what should I define? I have tried with several codes but nothing works.

Comment: For some other reason, I want to use Scrapy to perform this task. According to the website, it should be possible.

Comment: Updated parse() section.