# Download an online folder with Windows 10

Tags: r, windows, download, command-line-interface

I wish to download an online folder using Windows 10 on my Dell laptop.  In this example the folder I wish to download is named `Targetfolder`.  I am trying to use the Command Window but also am wondering whether there is a simple solution in R. I have included an image at the bottom of this post showing the target folder.  I should add that `Targetfolder` includes a file and multiple subfolders containing files.  Not all files have the same extension.  Also, please note this is a hypothetical site.  I did not want to include the real site for privacy issues.

**EDIT**

Here is a real site that can serve as a functional, reproducible example.  The folder `rel2020` can take the place of the hypothetical `Targetfolder`:

https://www2.census.gov/geo/docs/maps-data/data/rel2020/

None of the answers here seem to work with `Targetfolder`:

[How to download HTTP directory with all files and sub-directories as they appear on the online files/folders list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446635/how-to-download-http-directory-with-all-files-and-sub-directories-as-they-appear/61796867#61796867)

Below are my attempts based on answers posted at the link above and the result I obtained:

**Attempt One**

```
lftp -c 'mirror --parallel=300 https://www.examplengo.org/datadisk/examplefolder/userdirs/user3/Targetfolder/ ;exit'
```

Returned:

```
lftp is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

**Attempt Two**

```
wget -r -np -nH --cut-dirs=3 -R index.html https://www.examplengo.org/datadisk/examplefolder/userdirs/user3/Targetfolder/
```

Returned:

```
wget is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

**Attempt Three**

https://sourceforge.net/projects/visualwget/files/latest/download

`VisualWget` returned `Unsupported scheme` next to the `url`.

[image]

Comment: Try `httr::HEAD("https://www.examplengo.org")` and see you have a bad https address.

Comment: That is a R instruction, to be run at an R prompt, the question is tagged R. You must first install package `httr` with `install.packages("httr")`, then still at an R prompt, run the instruction above.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thank you.  When I do that I get the following five lines: `Response [https://www.examplengo.org/login.php]
  Date: 2022-05-29 23:46
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: text/html
<EMPTY BODY>`

Comment: That site doesn't seem to be available in my country, I'm getting `Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :  Could not resolve host: www.examplengo.org`. And in the browser it's also not available, so it's not an package `httr` error.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I should have stated in my post that the site is hypothetical. It does not exist anywhere.  I did not want to post the real site for privacy issues.  However, I have now added a real site to the post: https://www2.census.gov/geo/docs/maps-data/data/rel2020/ where `rel2020` takes the place of my hypothetical `Targetfolder`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way with packages `httr` and `rvest`.
First get the folders where the files are from the link.
Then loop through the folders with `Map`, getting the filenames and downloading them in a `lapply` loop.
If errors such as time out conditions occur, they will be trapped in `tryCatch`. The last code lines will tell if and where there were errors.

**Note:** I only downloaded from `folders[1:2]`, in the `Map` below change this to `folders`.

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(httr)
  library(rvest)
  library(dplyr)
})

link <- "https://www2.census.gov/geo/docs/maps-data/data/rel2020/"

page <- read_html(link)

folders <- page %>%
  html_elements("a") %>%
  html_attr("href") %>%
  .[8:14] %>%
  paste0(link, .)

files_txt <- Map(\(x) {
  x %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_elements("a") %>%
    html_attr("href") %>%
    grep("\\.txt$", ., value = TRUE) %>%
    paste0(x, .) %>%
    lapply(\(y) {
      tryCatch(
        download.file(y, destfile = file.path("~/Temp", basename(y))),
        error = function(e) e
      )
    })
}, folders[1:2])

err <- sapply(unlist(files_txt, recursive = FALSE), inherits, "error")
lapply(unlist(files_txt, recursive = FALSE)[err], simpleError)
```

Comment: Thank you.  I had no idea the solution would be so complex.  I suspect I will have to change the `grep` statement because my actual target folder contains files with multiple extensions.  There also is at least one `.txt` file that is not in any subfolder.   But this code is very nice.

Comment: @MarkMiller The main problem is not the 1st pipe where the folders names are determined, it's the 2nd. In each folder there are many files and `html_attr` returns them all so they must be downloaded in an inner loop, `lapply`. `grep`, `paste0` and `file.path` are just to put the filenames together, the important part is to get those names.