# PKIX path building failed

Tags: android, maven, authentication

I have set all plugins to work with `Maven` But when I am trying to compile my `Maven` project

using following command

```
 mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

I am getting following error in `cmd`

```
[ERROR] Error transferring file: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX
path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException
:unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Please help me in fixing this issue.

Comment: Error comes while downloading dependencies or compile?

Comment: @vinay yes at the time of downloading dependencies

Answer (score 1):

You will need to import HTTPS certificate of repository into java keystore or you can trust all certificates. 
Have a look at this [How to tell Maven to disregard SSL errors (and trusting all certs)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252800/maven-trusting-all-certs-unlimited-java-policy)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to add and specify java key store to get rid of these issues.

Full solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37108820/1802348)

simply download ssl certificate and use keytool to get jks file and specify that jks in MAVEN_OPTS environment variable.

But do not forget to put your jks file at project root i.e. just besides pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

If you feel the source is secure and it's just something with your network, firewalls or antivirus and you can't solve it with nothing else:

You can ignore the SSL certificate error on Maven.

Just add **-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true** to your Maven Options

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is wondering why `-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true` doesn't work to ignore SSL errors (like missing from trust store) since maven `3.9.0`, the answer is because they changed the transport from wagon to native HTTP, meaning the wagon props have no effect. For more information see [Maven docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-resolver-transport.html).

You have two options, to change the transport back to `wagon` (might not work in future) or instead use the new equivalent option `-Daether.connector.https.securityMode=insecure`
See overview of new transport options [here](https://maven.apache.org/resolver/configuration.html).