# How to configure Maven Wagon

Tags: maven, wagon, maven-wagon-plugin

[Maven Wagon HTTP documentation](http://maven.apache.org/wagon/wagon-providers/wagon-http/) says:

Other features can be configured through system properties:

```
maven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure = true/false (default false), enable/disable use of relaxed ssl check for user generated certificates.
maven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall = true/false (default false), enable/disable match of the server's X.509 certificate with hostname. If disabled, a browser like check will be used.
maven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates = true/false (default false), ignore issues with certificate dates.
maven.wagon.rto = time in ms (default 1800000), read time out.
```

Can this configuration also be done in settings.xml?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell Maven to disregard SSL errors (and trusting all certs)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252800/how-to-tell-maven-to-disregard-ssl-errors-and-trusting-all-certs)

Comment: @Stewart Not realy. This question is about configure these settings in `settings.xml` rather `-D...` start parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `wagon-2.9`: **NO**

All of them are using the `System.getProperty(...)` direct and are not configurable in `settings.xml`.

`maven.wagon.rto` (see #43 https://github.com/apache/maven-wagon/blob/wagon-2.9/wagon-providers/wagon-http/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/wagon/providers/http/HttpMethodConfiguration.java)

`maven.wagon.http.ssl.*` (see #235ff https://github.com/apache/maven-wagon/blob/wagon-2.9/wagon-providers/wagon-http/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/wagon/providers/http/AbstractHttpClientWagon.java)

Comment: Thanks. It seems like a rather hasty and inconvenient design decision, but maybe there's a good reason beyond my understanding. To me it's yet another bit of configuration in a singularly inconvenient place that's needed to get maven to work. I think system properties are reasonable for stuff that may change from one invocation to the next, e.g. -Dtest=... to run a single test. For this, not so much. It's a problem between the repo and the user and should be configurable in settings.xml

Comment: For future reference, system properties can be set in the pom.xml with the maven-properties plugin.

Answer (score 4):

[Since it is reading it from system properties](https://github.com/apache/maven-wagon/blob/master/wagon-providers/wagon-http/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/wagon/providers/http/AbstractHttpClientWagon.java#L235), it needs to be set like this

```
export MAVEN_OPTS=-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=false -DsomeOtherSystemProperty=value
```

- https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-maven.html

Comment: I know it's reading from system properties -- I was hoping that I could set the properties in settings.xml. Bleah. Another lose for maven.