# No plugin found for prefix 'exec' in the current project and in the plug in groups org.codehaus.mojo

Tags: java, spring, maven, maven-3, exec-maven-plugin

I have read several questions with similar issue and the Help 1 page. Unfortunately, I am stuck.

One possible reason could be caused by proxy but there is no such proxy here. Additionally, all maven projects in my PC have been successfully updated when I update it from Eclipse. So I discard this possibility.

Other thing I checked was to look for codehaus in my local repository and I find it (C:\Users\myUser.m2\repository\org\codehaus\mojo).

Another try, I tried add pluginGroups/pluginGroup in settings.
The project is a very simple hello word using spring batch with only a Tasklet and its execute method. There isn't public static void main method.

Command.exe with the whole error printed after I added the Matteo recommendation:

```
C:\temp\TaskletJavaConfig\spring-batch-helloworld>mvn compile exec:java -e
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentlib:jvmhook
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xrunjvmhook -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\PROGRA~2\HP\QUICKT~1\
bin\JAVA_S~1\classes;C:\PROGRA~2\HP\QUICKT~1\bin\JAVA_S~1\classes\jasmine.jar
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/exec-maven-p
lugin/1.1/exec-maven-plugin-1.1.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-
plugin:1.1: Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.1 or one of its depende
ncies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus
.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:jar:1.1
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven
-deploy-plugin/2.7/maven-deploy-plugin-2.7.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
n-deploy-plugin:2.7: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7 or
one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descripto
r for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:jar:2.7
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven
-site-plugin/3.3/maven-site-plugin-3.3.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
n-site-plugin:3.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3 or one
of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor fo
r org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:jar:3.3
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven
-antrun-plugin/1.3/maven-antrun-plugin-1.3.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
n-antrun-plugin:1.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3 or
one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descripto
r for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:jar:1.3
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven
-assembly-plugin/2.2-beta-5/maven-assembly-plugin-2.2-beta-5.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
n-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plu
gin:2.2-beta-5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read
artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:2.2-b
eta-5
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven
-dependency-plugin/2.8/maven-dependency-plugin-2.8.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
n-dependency-plugin:2.8: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin
:2.8 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact d
escriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.8
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven
-release-plugin/2.3.2/maven-release-plugin-2.3.2.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
n-release-plugin:2.3.2: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3
.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact des
criptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:jar:2.3.2
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metada
ta.xml
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven
-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/
to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.Valida
torException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertP
athBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xm
l from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator
.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.S
unCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested
target
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from https://
repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will
not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates
are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-
metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.securit
y.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider
.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path t
o requested target
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from h
ttps://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resoluti
on will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or u
pdates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.
plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.sec
urity.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certif
ication path to requested target
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.094 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-01-13T12:48:00-06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/123M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'exec' in the current project and in the plug
in groups [org.codehaus.mojo, org.apache.maven.plugins] available from the repos
itories [local (C:\Users\myUser\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.ap
ache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.NoPluginFoundForPrefixException: No plugin found
for prefix 'exec' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.codehaus.
mojo, org.apache.maven.plugins] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users
\myUser\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.internal.DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.r
esolve(DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.java:93)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.findPluginF
orPrefix(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:265)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.getMojoDesc
riptor(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:219)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalcul
ator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:103)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalcul
ator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:83)
       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(Lifecycl
eStarter.java:89)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
cher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
a:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
uncher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
356)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundF
orPrefixException

C:\temp\TaskletJavaConfig\spring-batch-helloworld>
```

Evidence that there is no proxy

```
C:\temp\TaskletJavaConfig\spring-batch-helloworld>netsh winhttp show proxy

Current WinHTTP proxy settings:

    Direct access (no proxy server).
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
       <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
       <groupId>com.test</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-batch-helloworld</artifactId>
       <version>20131227</version>
       <name>spring batch hello world</name>
       <packaging>jar</packaging>

       <!-- pluginRepositories>
              <pluginRepository>
                     <id>numberformat-releases</id>
                     <url>https://raw.github.com/numberformat/20130213/master/repo</url>
              </pluginRepository>
       </pluginRepositories-->

       <properties>
              <spring.framework.version>3.2.1.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
              <spring.batch.version>3.0.0.M2</spring.batch.version>
       </properties>

       <repositories>
              <repository>
                     <id>spring-s3</id>
                     <name>Spring Maven MILESTONE Repository</name>
                     <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
              </repository>
       </repositories>
       <dependencies>
              <dependency>
                     <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                     <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                     <version>2.6</version>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
                     <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
                     <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
                     <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
                     <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
                     <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
                     <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
                     <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                     <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                     <version>1.2.17</version>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
                     <groupId>junit</groupId>
                     <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                     <version>4.8.2</version>
                     <scope>test</scope>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
                     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                     <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                     <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
                     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                     <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                     <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
                     <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
                     <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
                     <version>1.8.0.7</version>
              </dependency>
       </dependencies>
<!-- added after Matteo recommendation-->
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <configuration>
 <mainClass>org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner</mainClass>
            <arguments>
                <argument>com.test.config.HelloWorldJobConfig</argument>
                <argument>helloWorldJob</argument>
            </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
       <!-- build>
              <plugins>
                     <plugin>
                           <groupId>github.numberformat</groupId>
                           <artifactId>blog-plugin</artifactId>
                           <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                           <configuration>
                                  <gitUrl>https://github.com/numberformat/wordpress/tree/master/${project.version}/${project.artifactId}</gitUrl>
                           </configuration>
                           <executions>
                                  <execution>
                                         <id>1</id>
                                         <phase>site</phase>
                                         <goals>
                                                <goal>generate</goal>
                                         </goals>
                                  </execution>
                           </executions>
                     </plugin>
              </plugins>
       </build-->

<!-- Run the application using:
mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner -Dexec.args="com.test.config.HelloWorldJobConfig helloWorldJob"
-->
</project>
```

Settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

  <pluginGroups>
               <pluginGroup>org.codehaus.mojo</pluginGroup>
  </pluginGroups>

   <proxies>
   </proxies>
   <servers>
   </servers>
   <mirrors>
   </mirrors>
   <profiles>
  </profiles>
</settings>
```

Logs with only mvn org.codehaus.mojo

```
C:\temp\TaskletJavaConfig\spring-batch-helloworld>mvn org.codehaus.mojo:exec-mav
en-plugin:1.1:java
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentlib:jvmhook
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xrunjvmhook -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\PROGRA~2\HP\QUICKT~1\
bin\JAVA_S~1\classes;C:\PROGRA~2\HP\QUICKT~1\bin\JAVA_S~1\classes\jasmine.jar
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/exec-maven-p
lugin/1.1/exec-maven-plugin-1.1.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.356 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-01-13T15:29:20-06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/123M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.1 or one of its dependencie
s could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.moj
o:exec-maven-plugin:jar:1.1: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.mojo:exec-
maven-plugin:pom:1.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun
.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.
provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certificatio
n path to requested target -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResoluti
onException

C:\temp\TaskletJavaConfig\spring-batch-helloworld>mvn compile mvn org.codehaus.m
ojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.1:java
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentlib:jvmhook
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xrunjvmhook -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\PROGRA~2\HP\QUICKT~1\
bin\JAVA_S~1\classes;C:\PROGRA~2\HP\QUICKT~1\bin\JAVA_S~1\classes\jasmine.jar
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/exec-maven-p
lugin/1.1/exec-maven-plugin-1.1.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.250 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-01-13T15:31:03-06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/123M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.1 or one of its dependencie
s could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.moj
o:exec-maven-plugin:jar:1.1: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.mojo:exec-
maven-plugin:pom:1.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun
.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.
provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certificatio
n path to requested target -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResoluti
onException
```

Comment: What happens if you open `https://
repo.maven.apache.org/maven2`? Seems you maven cannot access to remote repository and maybe uses corrupted local repository jars... Try to remove from your local repository (.m2/org/codehaus/mojo/exec-maven-plugin/1.1/)

Comment: can you update your settings with the output of mvn help:effective-settings?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should configure your pom file to at least declare the [Exec Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) as following:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

As such, you will be able to use the `exec:java` plugin:goal command.

---

You can even avoid the options:

```
-Dexec.mainClass=org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner -Dexec.args="com.test.config.HelloWorldJobConfig helloWorldJob"
```

By configuring them in your POM as part of the same plugin configuration as following:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner</mainClass>
        <arguments>
            <argument>com.test.config.HelloWorldJobConfig</argument>
            <argument>helloWorldJob</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

As you can see, we are actually saying to the plugin where to find the main class and its arguments. You could then hence simply invoke:

```
mvn compile exec:java
```

And it should perform the same expected results.

---

**Update1**
Indeed, your maven execution is having troubles to access the plugin metadata on the network:

> [WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-
>   plugin:1.1: Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus
>   .mojo:exec-maven-plugin:jar:1.1

---

**Update2**
If you keep on having issues with the plugin prefix, then indeed it might depend on your network settings. A quick check could be performed by invoking the Exec Maven Plugin not via its plugin prefix (`exec`) but via full qualified name as following:

```
mvn compile mvn org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.1:java
```

Note the pattern: we are invoking maven, then a groupId:artifactId:version:goal, it will be exactly the same. That will check whether your pom configuration (and plugin configuration) is correct or not.

---

**Update3**
As seen in your output log, Maven is trying to access repositories via `https` (note the final 's'), hence via SSL and then having issues with certificates as part of the build output:

> sun
>   .security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.
>   provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certificatio
>   n path to requested target

You have two options then:

- Tell maven to ignore SSL errors, as described in another [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252800/how-to-tell-maven-to-disregard-ssl-errors-and-trusting-all-certs/21266642#21266642)
- Check your settings firstly via running `mvn help:effective-settings` to make sure you get the real settings applied by maven (if the command will work actually), then re-configuring non SSL repositories in your settings with the alternative on another [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25912472/5606016)

Comment: Matteo, thanks for your answer but unfortunately I am still facing the same issue. I updated above with your suggestion in POM and the error message run with -e switch so you can see more details in logs.

Comment: could you try instead of mvn exec:java to execute: mvn org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.1:java? that should execute the goal without using the plugin prefix, just to check whether it will work out or not. I updated my answer (at its bottom) accordingly to make it clear.

Comment: Matteo, you are right. It failled only with codehaus. I find strange that I don't have proxy settup in my machine and I can open maven site from any browser. Additionaly, I tried to run straight from Eclipse (Sprint Tool Suite) and it run correctly. What could be wrong?

Comment: ok, I got it, if you look at your error log, maven is trying to download artefacts and plugin descriptor from https (note the final 's'), hence via SSL and then it is hitting a problem about certificates. So two solutions possible: either say to maven to ignore certificates errors or configure a non https repository, I'll update my answer accordingly with more details

Comment: Thanks. Your first SO answer didn`t work for me. In your second SO answer there are two options. The first one (security profiles) fixed my issue completely. The second (plugin repositories) keeps the same issue. P.S. only for helping future readers, after I fixed my issue, other issue triggered related to spring and I fixed it by changing the java, spring and spring batch to the most new ones.