# Could not calculate build plan - Eclipse Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

When I try building the project. The build fails with the following message.

```
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
```

I saw two similar questions and tried everything mentioned in the answers.

Things which I have tried.

1. The settings.xml changes which includes proxy in ~.m2/repository/settings.xml -- cannot download anything from eclipse at work. Got the proxy settings from IE>Internet Options>Connections>Lan Setting. When I use command prompt to check whether its correct or not, telnet [host][port] nothing is received.
2. Cleaning the Cache, m2 repository and updating the maven project, couldn't update it.
3. Tried downloading the maven plugins manually and tried putting it in .m2>repository>apache>maven>plugins>[respective plugin folder] tried rebuilding again the same error.

Basically everything is blocked here at workplace.

The settings.xml file contents are:-

```
<settings>
    <proxies>
        <proxy>
            <id>proxy</id>
            <active>true</active>
            <protocol>HTTP</protocol>
            <host>proxy.asdf.com</host>
            <port>6050</port>
        </proxy>
    </proxies>
</settings>
```

The pom.xml file contents are:-

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.asdfasdf.asdfsd</groupId>
    <artifactId>Service</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Service Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <springframework.version>4.2.0.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <jackson.version>2.5.3</jackson.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0/version> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>Service</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This is the error log.
[image: Error Log]

Please help.

Comment: Why maven-clean-plugin mentioned twice?

Comment: Sorry about that. Pasted that twice.

Comment: I strongly believe the problem is with your proxy. Your Maven is not able to connect to internet.

Comment: Normally most org now a days have their own internal maven repository when they restrict access to internet.  Have you checked if there is any internal repo which you can point your settings.xml at?

Comment: @Vijay I can check for that. Hopefully there is something like that.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote that your `settings.xml` is located in `~.m2/repository`. I think that's wrong. It should be placed in `~/.m2`.

Try to solve the problem step by step:

1. **Make sure maven is configured properly.**
   Place `settings.xml` within `~/.m2`.
   On command line, go into the project directory and invoke `mvn clean package`
2. After first step, handle eclipse

**Update**

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21266642/1988304) provides information about communicating via SSL. It shows how to disable certificate checking:

- `-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true` - enable use of relaxed SSL check for user generated certificates.
- `-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true` - enable match of the server's X.509 certificate with hostname. If disabled, a browser like check will be used.
- `-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true` - ignore issues with certificate dates.

Comment: That doesn't matter I guess. I am changing it manually and pointing it to the desired folder. Window>Preferences>Maven>Setting you can set it manually where the settings.xml is.

Comment: What happens if you call `mvn clean package` from command line, within project directory?

Comment: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target. I use eclipse.

Comment: Did that tried again. Didn't work. Have been stuck for quite some time now.