# Maven https errors with RAD/Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, ssl, ibm-rad

RAD 9.6.1 (Java 8) on Windows

Maven is the current culprit, but I'm betting this is Eclipse-wide/Java-wide. RAD errors showing this, on the project and pom.xml:

```
Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.itextpdf:itext-licensekey:jar:2.0.3
org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.itextpdf:itext-licensekey:jar:2.0.3
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:302)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:218)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:535)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:519)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:409)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:351)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:254)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:316)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:172)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.resolveDependencies(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:215)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:188)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:119)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.readMavenProject(MavenImpl.java:636)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.java:63)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refreshPhase2(ProjectRegistryManager.java:529)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager$3.call(ProjectRegistryManager.java:491)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager$3.call(ProjectRegistryManager.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:495)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:350)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:297)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.getProjectFacade(MavenBuilder.java:154)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:89)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:200)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:735)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:301)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:304)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:360)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:383)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:144)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:235)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact com.itextpdf:itext-licensekey:pom:2.0.3 from/to iText
(https://repo.itextsupport.com/releases): Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:287)
        ... 41 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact com.itextpdf:itext-licensekey:pom:2.0.3 from/to iText (https://repo.itextsupport.com/releases): Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
        at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$2.wrap(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:895)
        at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$2.wrap(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:1)
        at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$GetTask.flush(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:673)
        at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector.get(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:310)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:520)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
        ... 44 more

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
        at com.ibm.jsse2.j.a(j.java:3)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.j.a(j.java:32)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.as.b(as.java:691)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.as.a(as.java:710)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.as.i(as.java:338)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.as.a(as.java:711)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.as.startHandshake(as.java:454)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:242)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:159)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:175)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:120)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:330)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:319)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:241)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:271)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:228)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:199)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:79)
        at io.takari.aether.okhttp.OkHttpAetherClient.execute(OkHttpAetherClient.java:154)
        at io.takari.aether.okhttp.OkHttpAetherClient.get(OkHttpAetherClient.java:100)
        at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$GetTask.resumableGet(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:600)
        at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:453)
        at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector.get(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:304)
        ... 46 more
        pom.xml /Mail   line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
```

Or, when I run Maven from inside RAD, this:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project Mail: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project com.ibm.gs.houston:Mail:adapter:1.0-SNAPSHOT:
>   Failed to collect dependencies at
>   com.itextpdf:itext-licensekey:jar:2.0.3: Failed to read artifact
>   descriptor for com.itextpdf:itext-licensekey:jar:2.0.3: Could not
>   transfer artifact com.itextpdf:itext-licensekey:pom:2.0.3 from/to
>   iText (https://repo.itextsupport.com/releases): No appropriate
>   protocol, may be no appropriate cipher suite specified or protocols
>   are deactivated -> [Help 1]

I suspect it's not just [this site, but any site that no longer supports SSLv3](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=repo.itextsupport.com). I've seen this in WebSphere too, when it had [a setting to "SSL_TLS", which apparently doesn't do TLS 1.1 or 1.2](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/csec_sslconfigs.html). Finding what I hoped was the right RAD property file to address that setting, didn't seem to make any difference.

From the Eclipse configuration details, I see:

```
com.ibm.SSL.ConfigURL=file:C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP/runtimes/base_stub/properties/ssl.client.props
```

But changing settings there hasn't helped.

Comment: Another https problem with Maven in RAD, this one I can workaround with this technique: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46665598/796761. Doesn't help here, though, because the the itext http URL redirects to https. Even if it did, need https to work. I can't be the only one trying to use Maven under RAD with https?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be an Eclipse bug that isn't fixed until a later version than what RAD currently uses:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=515859

Answer (score 0):

An approach that works currently is to update RAD's `eclipse.ini` to point to a custom `java.security` file.

Edit the RAD eclipse.ini file to add something like:
`-Djava.security.properties=/Users/YourUsername/my.java.security`

Where `my.java.security` contains:

```sh
# explicitly don't use the WAS-provided SSL factory (from RAD).
# Use -Djava.security.properties=/Users/YourUsername/my.java.security in eclipse.ini
ssl.SocketFactory.provider=
ssl.ServerSocketFactory.provider=
```

Comment: Never mind, this isn't working for Maven Central. It worked for the iText repo, but not for Maven Central. For that, I still have in place the custom `settings.xml` forcing it not to use https. Grrr, grrr

Answer (score 0):

The latest update to RAD 9.6 uses Maven M2E 1.8.3, which does not experience the bug. The solution is to update your RAD 9.6 installation through IBM Installation Manager.