# Maven sonar plugin: trust self-signed certificate

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, self-signed

I try to launch `maven sonar:sonar` to a SonarQube instance on HTTPS connection with a self-signed certificate. Maven give me this error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar
>   (default-cli) on project data.model: Unable to execute SonarQube: Fail
>   to get bootstrap index from server:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note: Make sure you run `terminal as administrator` or with `sudo`**

**1. Run command to fetch certificate your sonarqube**

```
$ openssl s_client -showcerts -connect {domain}:{port}

example:
$ openssl s_client -showcerts -connect sonarqube.com:443
```

**2. Copy certificate to a new file `mycert.pem`**

[image]

New file: mycert.pem 
[image]

**3. Import the certificate to JDK->JRE**

```
$ keytool -importcert -file {filename}.pem -keystore "{jdk_path}/jre/lib/security/cacerts" -alias "{somename}" -storepass changeit

example:
$ keytool -importcert -file mycert.pem -keystore "/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_202/jre/lib/security/cacerts" -alias "MyCert" -storepass changeit
```

Type yes 
[image]

**4. Run SonarQube Command with your sonarqube link**

```
$ mvn clean package -U sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=https://sonarqube.com -Dsonar.projectKey=MyApp -Dsonar.projectName=MyApp -Dsonar.projectVersion=2.4.1 -Dsonar.language=java -Dsonar
.sources=src/main/java -Dsonar.tests=src/test/java '-Dsonar.exclusions=**/*Test*/**' -Dsonar.java.binaries=target/classes -Djavax.net.debug="ssl,handshake"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can [import the server certificate in your truststore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolfilex/rstep1.html):

```
keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias mySonarServer -file sonarServer.crt -keystore cacerts
```

Where `cacerts` is the one from the JRE installation.

Comment: I know this solution but i want that it is Maven to ignore this issue for agnostic platform execution

Comment: JVM has no option to turn off certificate validation, Maven wagon has a few options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252800/how-to-tell-maven-to-disregard-ssl-errors-and-trusting-all-certs
But Sonar plugin doesn't use wagon and doesn't provide a way to disable SSL certificate validation.