# Non-resolvable parent POM in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, pom.xml

I am trying to setup a Maven project for a Spring Boot application but while trying to save the pom.xml file I am getting this following issue:

---

> Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for
>   io.javabrains.springbootquickstart:course-api:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could
>   not find artifact
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:${revision} in
>   central (https://  repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) and
>   'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM

Here is my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">


  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>io.javabrains.springbootquickstart</groupId>
  <artifactId>course-api</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>Java Api course</name>


 <parent>
    <!-- Your own application should inherit from spring-boot-starter-parent -->
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2 RELEASE</version>
  </parent>



 <dependencies>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
   </dependency>
 </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Where should `${revision}` come from ?

Comment: I am following a tutorial where version is 1.4.2 RELEASE but still I was getting this error so, I searched for a demo file where ${revision} was there.

Comment: Then set your version to 1.4.2 RELEASE

Comment: Initially, I tried that only, but the error is same

Comment: imo https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.4.2.RELEASE/ is a valid url, could you again check  and post your error message for the 1.4.2 RELEASE?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved the issue.
There was a little mistake. It should be ***1.4.2.RELEASE*** instead of ***1.4.2 RELEASE***. There should not be space between *RELEASE and 2*. This little dot was causing the issue.

Answer (score 19):

This may be because of spring initializer created project pom file like this

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

However, sts is compatible with version "2.0.4.RELEASE", just make this change

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

further Maven -> Update Project

Comment: Upvoted, because it solved my issue in STS. How did you figure this out?

Comment: I did set up the project using sts and spring initializer separately and then the comparison of pom one by one.

Answer (score 4):

From where revision will be replaced ?

Modify `pom.xml` by specifying any version like below.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here :

```
<parent>
  <!-- Your own application should inherit from spring-boot-starter-parent -->
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>${revision}</version>
</parent>
```

`${revision}` will be interpolated by Maven (that is translated) only if Maven finds a variable with the `revision` name.
But `revision` is not a Maven built in variables. While variables as `${project.version}` and `${project.artifactId}` are.

So in your case, you have to declare or pass the variable explicitly if you want to use it.

For example it could work by adding it :

```
<properties>
  <revision>1.4.2 RELEASE</revision>
</properties>
```

Or by running maven such as : `mvn package -Drevision="1.4.2 RELEASE"`

You can find more information [here](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-model-builder/).

Note that a `revision` property appears to have a too broad meaning and doesn't help to understand the property meaning.
A more precise name such as `${spring-boot-version}` would make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2 RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

with

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
   <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Comment: Please add explanation

Answer (score 0):

Check your Proxy Settings.
In case you are working with a company PC that already has Proxys configured for browsers but not yet for your IDE or maven, you could probably enter the same information as for your browsers. You can find them e.g. by opening the network settings of your browser -> LAN Settings and then download the proxy.pac file from the address given in the input field. That file is human readable.

After that, you might still need to handle SSL errors by either

- correctly handling the company's own PKI or
- ignoring SSL errors or
- using http instead of https https://stackoverflow.com/a/46665598/1410212 NOT POSSIBLE ANYMORE SINCE 2020

Answer (score 0):

For me, actually AntiVirus was working in my system. So, I have disabled that for an hour and changed my version to 2.0.4.RELEASE and it works for me.