# Maven not using system keystore when custom trusstore provided

Tags: java, maven, ssl

We're using a private maven repository which uses a self signed SSL certificate. We've followed the guidelines from [Maven official documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-repository-ssl.html), which tells you to put your CA certificate in a custom trust store, then tell maven to use it using, for example, environment variable `MAVEN_OPTS`:
`MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx512m -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=trust.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=XXX`

This indeed fixes the SSL error for accessing our private repo, but now maven can't find the certificate to access Maven Central ! It seems that providing a custom trust store automatically disables using the system certificates for public repositories.

[Another very popular SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252800/how-to-tell-maven-to-disregard-ssl-errors-and-trusting-all-certs) gives a workaround, but to me disabling SSL isn't the solution.

I would expect that providing custom certificates just adds to those from the system.

We've though of adding all system trusted certificates to the custom truststore, but think it's a tedious solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot pass multiple truststores ( custom + system ) to `javax.net.ssl.trustStore`. When a truststore is passed to that property, it will basically ignore the system one, so that gives you 2 options:

1. Add all the system trusted certificates to your custom truststore ( cumbersome but is only one-time, or very rare, operation )
2. Get a certificate signed by a public CA. For example, you can get free certificates from https://letsencrypt.org/ ( it is a trusted public CA and did I mention that it is free? ). The only downside of let's encrypt is the validity of the certificates which currently they only issue them for a 3 month period.

Comment: We've also tried adding our custom CA certificate to the system trusted certificates, but maven does not seem to use system certificates at all. Is it using a system truststore ?

Comment: I don't really know what maven uses under the hood but why don't you do it the other way around? add the system trusted certificates to your custom truststore... in that way, you keep your system truststore intact and it will not impact other tools.

Comment: We'll do that :) Thanks for the advice !