# Gradle equivalent for Maven Wagon ssl insecure flag

Tags: java, maven, ssl, gradle, certificate

I know of the ability to [enable use of relaxed SSL check for user generated certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252800/how-to-tell-maven-to-disregard-ssl-errors-and-trusting-all-certs) by using the flag:

```
-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true
```

Is there any Gradle equivalent property?