# Error javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path while using ssl.insecure flag

Tags: java, maven, ssl, ssl-certificate, artifactory

I'm using Maven and Artifactory, and want to resolve pom.xml dependencies with an http connection. Therefore I use Maven wagon's flags [as specified here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252800/how-to-tell-maven-to-disregard-ssl-errors-and-trusting-all-certs)

I wonder how come I still get the error if I'm telling Maven to use insecure ssl connection.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/wagon/wagon-providers/wagon-http/):

> maven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure = true/false (false by default), enable/disable relaxed check of public key certificates (e.g. self-signed ones). Relaxed check means that any chain with 1 or more certificates will be considered valid if all the certificate dates in the chain are valid (dates check can be overridden as well - see below).

Relaxed checks doesn't mean there will be no checks at all ot it will switch to http without tls. From the message I understand there is no certificate path from the certificate presented by the server to any of the certs included in the truststore. You are likely missing some relevant cert in your truststore.