# Could not resolve JADE dependency

Tags: maven, pom.xml, agents-jade

I'm trying to add JADE as a maven dependecy.

I added the repository and the property.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>tilab</id>
        <url>https://jade.tilab.com/maven/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tilab.jade</groupId>
        <artifactId>jade</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Failed to execute goal on project jade: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.example:jade:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Cannot access tilab (https://jade.tilab.com/maven/) in offline mode and the artifact com.tilab.jade:jade:j
ar:4.6.0 has not been downloaded from it before

When I try to import the dependency, maven returns me:

*unable to find valid certification path to requested target*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Quick fix

### create `~/.mavenrc`

```
MAVEN_OPTS="-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true"
```

### Open Terminal

- Change to project folder.
- Run `mvn clean package`
- You will find download message

### My Test Code

```
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        └── java
            └── org
                └── example
                    └── Main.java
```

#### Main.java is not important

```
package org.example;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

#### pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>tmpmaven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>tilab</id>
            <url>https://jade.tilab.com/maven/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>com.tilab.jade</groupId>
           <artifactId>jade</artifactId>
           <version>4.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

#### Open Terminal

`mvn clean ackage`

```
$ mvn clean package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------< org.example:tmpmaven >------------------------
[INFO] Building tmpmaven 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
Downloading from tilab: https://jade.tilab.com/maven/com/tilab/jade/jade/4.3.3/jade-4.3.3.jar
Downloaded from tilab: https://jade.tilab.com/maven/com/tilab/jade/jade/4.3.3/jade-4.3.3.jar (2.7 MB at 317 kB/s)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ tmpmaven ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-
```

## How to find this answer?

### Try to use `curl` download `jade-4.6.0.pom`

```
$ curl https://jade.tilab.com/maven/com/tilab/jade/jade/4.6.0/jade-4.6.0.pom
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
...
```

Fail, Error message `SSL certificate problem`

### curl add -k skipping ssl problems

```
$ curl -k https://jade.tilab.com/maven/com/tilab/jade/jade/4.6.0/jade-4.6.0.pom
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
...
```

Add `-k`, to ignore SSL, it can success access.

### Then find `How to tell Maven to disregard SSL errors (and trusting all certs)?`

[How to tell Maven to disregard SSL errors (and trusting all certs)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252800/how-to-tell-maven-to-disregard-ssl-errors-and-trusting-all-certs)

Find answer.

- create ~/.mavenrc
- or add parameter after `mvn` command `-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true`

## This is quick fix

I don't care why ssl have error, just skip ssl

Answer (score 0):

You can get a working maven repository from [Jade's fork](https://jade-project.gitlab.io/page/download/)

**Repository to add to your pom**

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jitpack.io</id>
        <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

**Dependency to add to your pom**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.gitlab.jade-project</groupId>
    <artifactId>jade</artifactId>
    <version>master-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```