# Using Kafka With SSL Encryption but No Authentication (No Server Verification nor Client Authentication)

Tags: authentication, ssl, apache-kafka

Is it possible to use Kafka with SSL encryption but with no server verification nor client authentication?
I know that by default the latter is disabled, but is it possible to also disable the former?

Comment: Have you tried to use an `SSL` listener rather than `SASL_SSL`?

Comment: I tried SSL only.

Comment: Okay, that doesn't have SASL authentication, so whats the issue?

Comment: The issue is that Kafka by default demands server verification, i.e. that the client will know the server's certificate for the handshake to succeed.

Comment: Sure, but that sounds like the job of the certificate authority, not necessarily Kafka. Any keypair is going to require some handshake protocol

Comment: but let's say I don't have certificate authority and I'm using self signed certificates, is there a way to ignore certificate verification errors?

Comment: I'm not aware of any feature specific to Kafka for that. [That might be a JVM flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4663241/2308683)

Comment: I've completely forgot to thank you for all your help, @OneCricketeer! you really helped, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the similar problem. Since kafka is a java process, it will load the default jdk certs when running, which is under /usr/local/jdk/jre/lib/security/cacerts. if your server is trusted there, (in my scenario, my kakfa server is MSK, and is trusted already), then you don't have to config all the keys and certs.

So all in all, I only added kafka config of **security.protocol=SSL** and it worked.